# Force ssh to not print "Remote host identification has changed" warning

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to avoid ssh printing warning messages like this?

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Although the remote host identity has changed but I know it is fine and 
just want to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Four ways:

To just connect once to a system with a new host key, without having to answer questions, connect with the following option:

```
ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" this.one.host.name
```

To permanently remove the warning for *all* systems, edit your `~/.ssh/config` file to add the following lines:

```
Host *
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

To permanently remove all warnings for this *one* server, edit your `~/.ssh/config` file and add the following lines:

```
Host this.one.hostname
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

To remove the warning for this one change for this one server, remove the host key for that server from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. The next time you connect, the new host key will be added.

Comment: In the second option that configuration must be done in the server side which we are connecting to right?

Comment: No, it's your own `$HOME/.ssh/config` that matters in both the second and third option.

Comment: This still prints a warning for me (although it does allow the connection).

Answer (score 37):

Add this to your ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host 10.*                            # use your own pattern here, eg. *.example.com, example.*.com
  StrictHostKeyChecking   no         # turn off the HostKey check                                                               
  LogLevel                ERROR      # keep it from printing to STDOUT
  UserKnownHostsFile      /dev/null  # (optional) add the host automatically to a black hole, otherwise it would be added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts and show you a warning/message at the top of your session. You may want it added to known_hosts if your shell uses `ssh` autocompletion, such as fish.
```

Comment: MOD UP - only one that actually answered the question - this was the only answer to not just work, but SUPPRESS the WARNINGS.

Comment: Whoops, it appears users of fish shell won't be able to use the nice ssh autocompletion for previously connected hosts if they put UserKnownHostFile to /dev/null. Fish users and possibly everyone should not set that.

Comment: You better make a `ssh0` script/alias/function for `ssh -o UserKnowHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=ERROR` and use that expressly instead of dumping those options into `~/.ssh/config`. You may forget about them and then wonder why the checks didn't work when you just wanted them to work.

Answer (score 22):

You can take the line for that host out of `~/.ssh/known_host` (every host has a line as entry there).

Alternative is to use:

```
ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ....
```

Just using `-q` would have `ssh` silently fail.

Answer (score 12):

Not adding host keys to the default $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts is sometimes desirable.

Use `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` in addition to `-q` and `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to keep known_hosts uncluttered.  Here is an example:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q user@scripts.local
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative suggestion is to identify why the host key is changing, and get it to stop doing that.

As an example:  if you're building hosts in containers or through a provisioning system, ensure that these consistently use the same known host key per instance.

I'm well aware this isn't always possible, and hosts may be managed outside your scope of control, but those hostkey warnings are there for a reason and are significant.  Reducing the exception count is a Good Thing.

Otherwise, I vote for [StrictHostKeyChecking No](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110561/266086) in your `~/.ssh/config` **for the specific host in question only.**